# How to get the changed object of an array when using ember oberver

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using following code to get the details of the object whose property is changed.

```
getChangedObject:function(){
    console.log('changed name is' , can i get the object here );
}.observes('model.@each.rollNo')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess. its not possible right now.

Comment: Are you sure that we don't have any property in the model that we can know it is changed?

Comment: To get changedAttributes in particular model, you can refer [changedAttributes api](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_changedAttributes). But your question is different, ie, From array of object which particular object's `rollNo` change causes this observer to trigger, that is not possible to get particular changed object alone (i guess).

Comment: But inside observer you can manually iterate `model` array and can look for the changedAttributes  alone

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you cannot get what is changed. But you can keep the currentValue at your observer. So you can find the changed property by getting a diff of values.

Comment: yes. `changedAttribures()` did not solve my problem :(

Comment: if you can elaborate your exact use case or problem? some one will guide you to an answer.

Comment: You cant. For this you would have to register the observer on every single item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Inside observer you cant get the exact object which caused observer to trigger, but you can try the below approach, like iterating array of model and watch for changed attributes alone.

```
getChangedObject: function() {
        let model = this.get('model');
        model.forEach(function(item, index) {
            var changedAttributes = item.changedAttributes();
            item.eachAttribute(function(item, meta) {
                var temp = changedAttributes[item];
                if(temp){
                 console.log(' old value ',temp[0],' new value ',temp[1]);
                }
            });
        })
    }.observes('model.@each.rollNo')
```

Comment: As per the instruction in [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_changedAttributes), `changedAttributes()` gives changed attributes until the record is saved. This does not solve my problem.

Comment: if the model is created locally not yet saved then you wont get changed attributes but for saved or already loaded records you will get....,if it's not suitable to you then may be you can try saving earlier state of an object and compare with current state by yourself. you might be initially thought of writing that one .